# while loop turning into an infinite loop for non bool values

Tags: c++, boolean

When I input 0 or 1 to the program, it works as expected ( outputs the value and takes another ) , but if I input anything else, an infinite loop keeps printing 1 1 1 1....

```
int main(){
    do{
        bool a;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }
    while(true);
}
```

why did that happen ?

Comment: `if (!(cin>>a)) throw "Oops";` ... you're not checking for failure.

Comment: when extraction from the stream fails then the input is still in the stream and next extraction fails again

Comment: I didn't know of failure, thanks !

Comment: This is *always* an infinite loop. It just waits for more after valid input